# How do i make a Name Saves and Load when i open the batch file everytime

Tags: batch-file

How do I make a batch file like I type my name, it shows, but when I close it, it disappeared! I need something to save my name so it won't dissappear every time I close and Open the Batch File!

I tried this: `echo %text%>> random.dll` And I THOUGHT This will Work! And will Always Show Up every time when I close and Open! It didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting the unknown value of `%text%` to a `dll` file, which by the way is now simply a plain text file since you wrote plain text to it, will not mysteriously summon your name each time you run a batch-file.

Here are a few ways to do this:

1. Save the batch-file name as your name for instance `Gboy.cmd` then use `%~n0` which is the name of the file excluding extension.

```
@echo off
set "myname=%~n0"
echo %myname%
```

2. save the name to a file and read it each time:

```
@echo off
(echo Gboy)>namefile.txt
<namefile.txt set /p myname=
echo %myname%
```

3. use `setx` to save a permanent environment variable. Be careful with this however as you must consider what you create as a variable name and not overwrite any existing system variable:

```
if not defined myname setx myname gboy && set "myname=gboy"
echo %myname%
```

4. it is also quite possible that the name you want to use is already set as your system variable `%username%` in the required format:

```
@echo off
echo %username%
```